# I am trying to use the below code on eclipse for Retrieving Json Array using JsonPath . Its giving me error

Tags: json, eclipse, import, rest, jsonpath

\import Files.Payload;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;

public class complexJsonParse {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    
    JsonPath js=new JsonPath(Payload.CoursePrice());
    
    int count=js.get("courses.size()");
    System.out.println(count);
    
    
    
}
```

}

Error is

Exception in thread "main" io.restassured.path.json.exception.JsonPathException: Failed to parse the JSON document
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$ExceptionCatcher.invoke(JsonPath.java:1002)
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$4.doParseWith(JsonPath.java:967)
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$JsonParser.parseWith(JsonPath.java:1047)
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.get(JsonPath.java:202)
at complexJsonParse.main(complexJsonParse.java:12)
Caused by: groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 2, column: 6, while reading 'p', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.
at groovy.json.JsonLexer.nextToken(JsonLexer.java:86)
at groovy.json.JsonLexer$nextToken.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parseObject(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:227)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:193)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:61)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parse(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:105)
at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper$parse.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parseText(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:83)
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$4$1.method(JsonPath.java:965)
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$ExceptionCatcher.invoke(JsonPath.java:1000)
... 4 more

Comment: Seems to be invalid JSON: `Lexing failed on line: 2, column: 6, while reading 'p', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.` Unfortunately, your question does not show the JSON.

Comment: {
  "courses": [
    {
      "title": "Selenium Python",
      "price": 50,
      "copies": 6
    },
    {
      "title": "Cypress",
      "price": 40,
      "copies": 4
    },
    {
      "title": "RPA",
      "price": 45,
      "copies": 10
    }
  ],
  "dashboard": {
    "purchaseAmount": 910,
    "website": "rahulshettyacademy.com"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this using `getInt()`

```
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JsonPath jsonPath = JsonPath.from("{ \"courses\": [ { \"title\": \"Selenium Python\", \"price\": 50, \"copies\": 6 }, { \"title\": \"Cypress\", \"price\": 40, \"copies\": 4 }, { \"title\": \"RPA\", \"price\": 45, \"copies\": 10 } ], \"dashboard\": { \"purchaseAmount\": 910, \"website\": \"rahulshettyacademy.com\" } }");
    
    int count=jsonPath.getInt("courses.size()");
    System.out.println(count);
  }
}
```

This is a minimal working sample. It outputs: `3`